# How to prevent an iPad from grabbing Apple ID for "Itunes and App Store" when plugged into a Mac?

Tags: itunes, ipad, icloud, messages, apple-id

I work as an iOS developer and have a number of development iPads at work. They are generic ipads used for testing and demos, none should apple ID.

When I plug such iPad into my mac, two things seems to happen:

1. iTunes opens and offers me to "set up my new iPad", even if it is already setup
2. I close iTunes
3. I unplug the iPad, but now it has my personal apple ID remembered in "iTunes and app store" in preferences.

Now at random intervals the ipad asks me for the password for this user ID. I think it even tries to convert that into an iCloud ID. Even worse, I randomly get popups saying "[some random generic company ipad] now uses my apple ID for facetime and iMessage".

**How can I permanently lock generic iPads into something so it does not grab my personal apple ID and use it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to get this issue as well and what I did was to prevent iTunes from auto syncing when I connect a device, this option is found in the iTunes Preferences/Devices and tick the checkbox as shown in the screenshot

[image: iTunes Prefrences/Devices]

It's also worth going into the user preferences then login items and remove "iTunes helper" which should stop it from launching iTunes anytime you connect a device.